# Calculated Fields in MYsql

Tags: mysql

Excuse the "newbee to modern Databases" question in advance.  But  have a very simple question.

Given the following table:

```
ID   Cost_Goods     Sales_Price
1    100            150
2    75             95
3    500            700
```

I know that I can Query

```
SELECT Cost_Goods FROM someTable WHERE ID =2;
```

Very often I would like to know 'profit'  where Profit is calculated  as in:

```
SELECT profit FROM someTable WHERE ID =2;
```

I know that I can use a function here.  But I have some limitations form a whole lot of legacy code.  I wish to cmd up with a way to have a sort of "Calculation Field" in the database itself.  That would, in addition to the above "profit" query allow me to query like.

```
SELECT Cost_Goods, profit FROM someTable WHERE ID =2;
```

Or Even:

```
  SELECT * FROM someTable ORDER BY profit;
```

Is this possible?

I understand that there are more elegant ways to hand the calculation,  but the interface from the application that I am working on/in simply don't allow anything other than avery simple query.  I am attempting to shift the calculation over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either alter the table to add in a column, maybe ideal maybe not, but this would require that the new field be kept up-to-date on each Insertion.  Not a problem if you have control over this, but can come back and bite you if you think you updated all your INSERTS when in fact you haven't.

I think the preferred way would be to do the calculation in SQL

```
SELECT Cost_Goods -Sales_Price AS profit FROM someTable ORDER BY profit
```

Or if you can create a view in the database...

```
 CREATE VIEW sales_profit AS SELECT  ID, Cost_Goods, Sales_Price, Cost_Goods -Sales_Price AS profit FROM someTable;
```

Then you can..

```
 SELECT * FROM sales_profit where ID = 2;
 SELECT * FROM sales_profit ORDER BY profit;
```